# calling odata api on postman returns 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: c#, api, odata

When I try to return an object using the odata method, I get the following error:

```
406 Not Acceptable
```

This is my code:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using APIDemo.Repositories;
using APIDemo.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;

namespace APIDemo.Controllers
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class MyapitestController : ODataController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var myclass = new MyClass()
            {
                Name = "Someone"
            };
            return Ok(myclass);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult Put([FromODataUri] string key, MyClass body)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(MyClass test)
        {
            return Ok();
        }   
    }
}
```

If I return a string in the Get() method, as follows: return Ok("some test"), this works fine. But when I try to return the class MyClass, it throws the error as you can see below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post your webapiconfig file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check if you are using the same class in the configuration builder in webapiconfig.cs as you are using in your Controller.cs class.

```
    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "AirFlights";

        builder.EntitySet<Person>("People");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
```

Controller:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using APIDemo.Repositories;
using APIDemo.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;

namespace APIDemo.Controllers
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class PeopleController : ODataController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var myclass = new Person()
            {
                Name = "Someone"
            };
            return Ok(myclass);
        }
    }
}
```

Or sometimes this occurs when referencing the wrong namespace, but in this case you are referencing the right ones:

```
using APIDemo.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
```